# How to JOIN into a array inside another array using CosmosDB SQL API?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have created a sample doc in order to show my issue:

```json
    {
        "brand": "foobar",
        "sellPrice": {
            "salesMarkets": [
                {
                    "salesMarket": "DK",
                    "channels": [
                        {
                            "channelId": 1,
                            "channelName": "Store",
                            "priceValue": 80,
                            "currencyISOCode": "DKK"
                        },
                        {
                            "channelId": 2,
                            "channelName": "Online",
                            "priceValue": 80,
                            "currencyISOCode": "DKK"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "salesMarket": "SE",
                    "channels": [
                        {
                            "channelId": 1,
                            "channelName": "Store",
                            "priceValue": 100,
                            "currencyISOCode": "SEK"
                        },
                        {
                            "channelId": 2,
                            "channelName": "Online",
                            "priceValue": 100,
                            "currencyISOCode": "SEK"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "id": "6e9b825d-9154-4bef-b52b-2badb46b3c53"
    }
```

my query looks like follows

```sql
    SELECT c.brand, sm.salesMarket, ch.channelName
    FROM c
    JOIN sm IN c.sellPrice.salesMarkets
    JOIN ch IN c.sellPrice.salesMarkets.channels
    WHERE c.brand = 'foobar'
```

I expected the output to be as follows:

```json
    [
        {
            "brand": "foobar",
            "salesMarket": "DK",
            "channels": [
                {
                    "channelName": "Store"
                },
                {
                    "channelName": "Online"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "brand": "foobar",
            "salesMarket": "SE",
            "channels": [
                {
                    "channelName": "Store"
                },
                {
                    "channelName": "Online",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I just cannot figure out how to make the second join do what I need. The first join works as expected but as soon as I add the second one I get 0 results

Comment: Can you please edit your question to explain what you mean by "things fail"? Are there errors? Do you get different output than expected?

Comment: change **JOIN ch IN c.sellPrice.salesMarkets.channels** to **JOIN ch IN sm.channels** can get result but not your ideal result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can accept this result.

```
SELECT c.brand, sm.salesMarket,sm.channels FROM c
JOIN sm IN c.sellPrice.salesMarkets 
where c.brand='foobar'

[
    {
        "brand": "foobar",
        "salesMarket": "DK",
        "channels": [
            {
                "channelId": 1,
                "channelName": "Store",
                "priceValue": 80,
                "currencyISOCode": "DKK"
            },
            {
                "channelId": 2,
                "channelName": "Online",
                "priceValue": 80,
                "currencyISOCode": "DKK"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "brand": "foobar",
        "salesMarket": "SE",
        "channels": [
            {
                "channelId": 1,
                "channelName": "Store",
                "priceValue": 100,
                "currencyISOCode": "SEK"
            },
            {
                "channelId": 2,
                "channelName": "Online",
                "priceValue": 100,
                "currencyISOCode": "SEK"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```